# Open a json file from a link with InputStream in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

i can open the Json file from assets folder using this code

```
 companion object{
        fun parseFile(context: Context, fileNameJson: String): CoinResponse{
            val inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileNameJson)
            val jsonObject = Json.parse(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            val coins = mutableListOf<Coin>()
```

but when i try to open it from a link "http://myurl.com/file.json" i got "  java.io.FileNotFoundException " in this line below:

```
val inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileNameJson)
```

note: i'm already using thread to read the Url and i can see the Json file content in the logcat

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
> io.horizontalsystems.bankwallet.core.App:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: {
> "version": 3,
> "coins": [
> {
> "title": "Next Gen Finance",
> "code": "NXGN",
> "decimal": 18,
> "type": "bep20",
> "address": "0x260A4A7849D65E7d4aEE31Fcf5c917c5a977e985"
> },
> {
> "title": "Bitcoin",
> "code": "BTC",
> "decimal": 8,
> "type": "bitcoin"
> },
> {
> "title": "Litecoin",
> "code": "LTC",
> "decimal": 8,
> "type": "litecoin"
> },
> {
> "title": "Ethereum",
> "code": "ETH",
> "decimal": 18,
> "type": "ethereum"
> },
> {
> "title": "Bitcoin Cash",
> "code": "BCH",
> "decimal": 8,
> "type": "bitcoinCash"
> },
> {
> "title": "Dash",
> "code": "DASH",
> "decimal": 8,
> "type": "dash"
> }
> ]
> }
>
> ```
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6998)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:270)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2051)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
>  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
> ```

how can i open a json file from link instead of a local assets folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager#open(java.lang.String)):

> Open an asset using ACCESS_STREAMING mode. This provides access to files that have been bundled with an application as assets -- **that is, files placed in to the "assets" directory.**

Thus, if you want to get the content of a remote a file via URL, you should check "how to make a HTTP request"

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm using this to read the URL 
" val result = URL("http://myurl.com/myfile.json").readText() " , isn't enough? please i need more help in this point

Comment: @KamalCherkaoui just try it

Comment: i used Klaxon Lib 

`val result = URL("http://medizag.com/coins.json").readText()
                    val parser: Parser = Parser()
                    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(result)
                    val jsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject

                    val coins = mutableListOf<Coin>()

                    val version = jsonObject.asObject().get("version").asInt()
                    jsonObject.asObject().get("coins").asArray().forEach { category ->`

Comment: but i got this " Unresolved reference: asObject "

Comment: @KamalCherkaoui this is another problem, and you should try to solve it yourself (since it's actually pretty straightforward )

Comment: i really appreciate your help, just tell me what is the problem, and i will fix it by myself. i'm already stuck with this since 3 days

Comment: `Unresolved reference: asObject` -> the problem is a `.asObject()` call I would say... (probably because `JsonObject` does not have a `asObject` method)